# How to convert 3650 columns (temperature) from Kelvin to Celsius?

Tags: r, dataframe, temperature

I have a data frame with 10 years of daily temperature data. I want to convert all the values to Celsius. So I have 3.653 columns and 500 rows.

A sample of my data looks like below:

```
    
Location_ID     day1_2010     day2_2010     day3_2010    day4_2010 
------------------------------------------------------------------
1345             301             302         345          320
2375             305             302         345          320
3126             311             299         305          320
```

Comment: And what di you try to do so far? Please share some code and tell us where exactly you need help. In addition: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just subtract from all columns but the ID column 273.15.

```
DF[-1] <- DF[-1] - 273.15
DF
#   Location_ID day1_2010 day2_2010 day3_2010 day4_2010
# 1        1345     27.85     28.85     71.85     46.85
# 2        2375     31.85     28.85     71.85     46.85
# 3        3126     37.85     25.85     31.85     46.85
```

---

*Data*

```
DF <- structure(list(Location_ID = c(1345L, 2375L, 3126L), day1_2010 = c(301L, 
305L, 311L), day2_2010 = c(302L, 302L, 299L), day3_2010 = c(345L, 
345L, 305L), day4_2010 = c(320L, 320L, 320L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thank a lot. I am very new at this. This solution was so simple!

Comment: @mgdata Very welcome! I recommend that you look into the vectorization of R in more detail.

Comment: Thanks! I will do that.

Answer (score 1):

A `tidyverse` approach, where you can define your own function

```
library(dplyr)

your_data_frame %>%
  mutate(across(.cols = starts_with('day'),.fns = function(x) x - 273.15))

Location_ID day1_2010 day2_2010 day3_2010 day4_2010
1        1345     27.85     28.85     71.85     46.85
2        2375     31.85     28.85     71.85     46.85
3        3126     37.85     25.85     31.85     46.85
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `kelvin.to.celsius` from `weathermetrics` package (without needing to know the conversion factor) to do the conversion.  Loop `across` the 'day' columns and apply the function on the columns, and update by assigning back to the same object

```
library(dplyr)
library(weathermetrics)
df1 <- df1 %>%
    mutate(across(starts_with('day'), kelvin.to.celsius, round = 2))
```

-output

```
df1
Location_ID day1_2010 day2_2010 day3_2010 day4_2010
1        1345     27.85     28.85     71.85     46.85
2        2375     31.85     28.85     71.85     46.85
3        3126     37.85     25.85     31.85     46.85
```

---

Or use `collapse` if the data is big

```
library(collapse)
get_vars(df1, regex =TRUE, vars = '^day') <- dapply(get_vars(df1, 
      regex =TRUE, vars = '^day'), MARGIN = 2, kelvin.to.celsius)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Location_ID = c(1345L, 2375L, 3126L), day1_2010 = c(301L, 
305L, 311L), day2_2010 = c(302L, 302L, 299L), day3_2010 = c(345L, 
345L, 305L), day4_2010 = c(320L, 320L, 320L)),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```